# XAML data binding, object does not match target type

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have 2 different group page with 2 look alike classes which using the same technique

This for 1st group page named as NewsFeed

```
<!-- Collection of grouped items displayed by this page -->
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}" IsSourceGrouped="true"
    ItemsPath="Items" d:Source="{Binding ItemGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:NewsFeedDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

to pass the group data into the group page.

This for 2nd group page named as Event

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}" IsSourceGrouped="true"
    ItemsPath="Items" d:Source="{Binding ItemGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:EventDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

and some of the code sample which binding with the ViewSource above

```
 <GridView x:Name="itemGridView" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView" AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items" Margin="116,0,40,46"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

                        <GridView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                                            <Button
                                        AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                        Content="{Binding Title}"
                                        Click="Header_Click"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TextButtonStyle}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.Panel>
                            </GroupStyle>
                        </GridView.GroupStyle>
                    </GridView>
```

and the static resources which binding to 250x250 template code will be

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard250x250ItemTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderRectBrush}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayTextBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryTextBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Even that the whole app able to work well. But i found there is a line bottom of either 1 source code above. The blue line show tat the object does not match target type.

Anyone knw wat happening to the code? =D 
Sorry if i didn't post up all information. Is kinda big. Please request if require more info.

Comment: Could you post 2 more things.. I think I have an idea.. Could you show us the XAML lines where the NewsFeedDataSource and EventDataSource are set and could you verify that you are setting (in regular code) the appropriate value in the DefaultViewModel collection (the one being used by the DataSource)?

Comment: @DevTheo
Did u create window 8 metro app b4? It just exactly the same as the sample while i just duplicate the same set of classes and edit some of the info inside. Anyway as u request, i try to put the related code as well =D

Comment: Actually that was what I was getting at.. I ran into something like this with a sample I have. In my case I have several things wrong.. most notably that my DefaultViewModel referred to a different source.. (although I also had some misnamed items too)..

Comment: Cause by using the data binding technology, the name is really important cause the data binding r referring to the name of the component. Thus, although different source, the name should be different i guess.

Comment: Well, think about the fact that they have baked into WINRT/XAML the ability to have multiple datasets (viewmodels) that you can bind stuff to.. It's nice, BUT really confusing when you first run into it.. (again, I was just making sure you were binding to what you thought you were binding to.. )

Comment: True true is kinda confusing >< 
Anyway thanks for developers here which help beginners always =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few more testing, i found that this problem caused due to the same name for itemspath and d:Source. 
The code should as least look like

```
   <UserControl.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}" IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="EventItems" d:Source="{Binding EventItemGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:EventDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

and

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- Collection of grouped items displayed by this page -->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}" IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items" d:Source="{Binding ItemGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:NewsFeedDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```